# Why am I getting "Type does not exist" error adding a new razor page using entity framework

Tags: visual-studio, razor-pages

I am experimenting with Visual Studio 2022 and EF Core 6. I created a solution with three projects, one with my razor pages one with my dbcontext and one with my entity. I was able to get the migration working with no issue, creating the database and single table which to me indicates I have everything working properly, but when I go to add a razor page and allow VS to wire up a "List" template for me, it spins for a minute and gives me an error: A type with the name Scaffolding.Entities.EncylopediaEntry does not exist.

Here is the class that apparently doesn't exist

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Scaffolding.Entitites
{
    public class EncylopediaEntry
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; } 
    }
}
```

And here is the DbContext with a hard coded connection string for now as I'm trying to figure out why scaffolding isn't working

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Scaffolding.Entitites;

namespace ScaffoldingTest.Data
{
    public class ScaffoldingContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<EncylopediaEntry> encyclopediaEntries { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("{remove}");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: The parameters I am using for scaffolding]

Comment: What target framework are each of your three projects targeting?

Comment: Each of the three project is targeting net6.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd got same error. Visual Studio 2022 (preview too) with NET 6.0.
I installed NET 5.0 and tested with new project net 5 then works well.
But not with NET 6.0.

Comment: Thank you for double checking this, I greatly appreciate it. It looks like I should figure out how to report this to Microsoft.

Comment: I have this same issue, on fresh install of 2022 with Data Tools installed.  Not sure how to troubleshoot this being new.  I'm using the Report a Problem tool in VS to report the issue.

Comment: Issue fixed in the new 6.0.1 package. [https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/1705](https://github.com/dotnet/Scaffolding/issues/1705). Thanks for the answers.